# Orange Biolab Pivot Table widget - missing

Tags: orange

I downloaded most recent version of Orange. I can not find the Pivot Table widget anywhere. When right clicking on the search menu shown, it does not appear anything when writing Pivot Table phrase.

Here is the link to the documentation on this widget:

https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/widgets/data/pivot.html